# Column Headers in Telerik- RaddataGrid

Tags: xaml, uwp, telerik-grid

I want to show the column names inside the group headers that I have created in the Raddatagrid. I have searched the documentation of the Telerik but there is no approach provided for this specific requirement.

Comment: Does the [GroupHeaderTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/windows-universal/controls/raddatagrid/features/grouping/datagrid-styling) meet your requirement?

Comment: No, because the group headers are always inside the column headers

Comment: I'm not sure which effect you want. Could you draw a sketch to let me know what it looks like?